# sql Update specific rows from select query

Tags: sql

Hello I need some awful stored procedure and I cannot think of such

I've got these tables

**Criterias**

```
CriteriaId
Title
.......
```

Table **StepCriterias**

```
StepID
CriteriaId
OrderNum
```

Table **Steps**

```
StepID
ProcedureID
Title
...
```

So I select all the `StepCriterias` of a step with particular name and particular number

```
SELECT * 
FROM StepCriterias sc 
INNER JOIN Steps s ON sc.StepId = s.StepId
WHERE 
    s.Title = 'MYteststep'
    ANd s.ProcedureId = 2
```

So suppose this query returns me five rows; now I should `UPDATE` all the resulting rows and their `OrderNum` should be incremented by 1 (I should increase the `OrderNum` of each row). That's my first problem and I cannot think of a stored procedure that an make that.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, what if one `stepcriteria` matches more than once?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this way .

```
UPDATE sc
SET OrderNum = OrderNum + 1 
FROM StepCriterias sc 
INNER JOIN steps s ON sc.StepId = s.StepId
WHERE s.Title = 'MYteststep'
  AND s.ProcedureId = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `join` logic with an `exsits` condition in an `update` statement:

```
UPDATE StepCriterias sc
SET    OrderNum = OrderNum + 1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   steps s 
               WHERE  sc.StepId = s.StepId AND
                      s.Title = 'MYteststep' AND
                      s.ProcedureId = 2)
```

Comment: @MilkaSalkova What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UPDATE` with a subquery, something like:

```
UPDATE StepCriterias 
SET OrderNum = sc.OrderNum + 1 
WHERE StepId IN (SELECT StepId 
                 FROM StepCriterias sc 
                 INNER JOIN steps s ON sc.StepId = s.StepId
                 WHERE s.Title = 'MYteststep' AND s.ProcedureId = 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you want an increment for *each* match, and a `stepcriteria` could match more than once, then:

```
UPDATE StepCriterias sc
    SET OrderNum = (OrderNum + 
                    (SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM steps s 
                     WHERE sc.StepId = s.StepId AND
                           s.Title = 'MYteststep' AND
                           s.ProcedureId = 2
                    )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM steps s 
                  WHERE sc.StepId = s.StepId AND
                        s.Title = 'MYteststep' AND
                        s.ProcedureId = 2
                 );
```

There are simpler ways to express this in most databases, but the above is general syntax that should work in any database.